# Get Substring of QString by Pixels in Qt cpp

Tags: c++, qt, pixel, qstring, qfontmetrics

I have a `QString` who's pixel length I can get by `QFontmetrics::width()`, also I can have character length from `QString` by `QString::length()`, but here I am intended to **cut `QString` by specific amount of pixels.**

Is there any way possible to have substring from `QString` by giving pixel size?

Thanks!

Comment: And suppose you cut right through a letter, how are you supposed to partially display it?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think that as the OP want a substring, the partial character problem is out of scope... in that case the method should either exceed the length adding a character or, probably the best way, omit it in order to fit the desired width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`QFontMetrics::elidedText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#elidedText) to do so. For example, to cut at 200 pixels use:

```
QString cutString = yourFontMetrics.elidedText(someString, Qt::ElideNone, 200);
```

The second parameter indicates the *cut* mode (more values [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextElideMode-enum)).

**UPDATE**: I'm not sure if it is a bug in Qt (Qt 5.10.0 for me), but indeed the `Qt::ElideNone` returns the same string. Here a workaround:

```
QString cutString(const QString& str, const QFontMetrics& fm, int pixels)
{
  const QChar ellipsis(0x2026);
  if (fm.width(str) <= pixels) return str;
  auto tmpStr = fm.elidedText(str, Qt::ElideRight, pixels + fm.width(ellipsis));
  return tmpStr.left(tmpStr.length() - 1);
}
```

A whole working example can be found [here](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/51701467-get-substring-of-qstring-by-pixels-in-qt-cpp) (you will need to add files to a new Qt project).

Comment: if I add Qt::ElideLeft it works , but i want it to be without ellipsis. Thanks!

Comment: @karanchavan interesting, it seems to be a bug or a discrepancy with documentation. I've added a workaround to it that will remove the ellipsis. Thanks for pointing this out, I've always used it with ellipsis ;)

Comment: @karanchavan, sorry, I've updated the code, copied the wrong version from tests